# Does ionic push notification work even if the app is closed or minimized?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and trying to learn it.I wanted to know whether  ionic push notification work even if the app (android or ios) is closed or minimized . Please provide this information with respect to both development and production versions of ionic push notification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch):

All you need to do to get your app receiving notifications is add the following snippet somewhere. To ensure that it's always registered, we're going to put in inside the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` section within app.js file. This will create an instance of the push service and register your app for notifications each time it is opened.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
Ionic.io(); 

var push = new Ionic.Push({
  "debug": true
});

push.register(function(token) {
  console.log("Device token:",token.token);
});
});
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Milad for your reply , but as per http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-development-mode , Development pushes are meant for testing on small numbers of installs, and should not be used at scale. The device tokens generated for dev pushes only function for two hours, and "only while the app is open". So, here , I am a bit confused, because if ionic push notification is not useful in sending push notification when the app is closed, then what is the whole point of using it ?

Comment: @SiddhikaChhelavda what you said is true but just in "Development Mode" and for other pushes it works even if app is closed. ;)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this :) This has been of great help to me